# How prove in triangle that if $AE \le AC$, then $AE + EC \le AC + BD$

Tags: geometry

Given a triangle ABC. On its side BC marked points D and E such that they lie in the order B, D, E, C, and there $\angle DAB = \angle EAD = \angle CAE$. How prove that if $AE  \le AC$, then $AE + EC  \le AC + BD$. I have no idea how to do this, can this be proved with simple geometry?

[image]

Comment: At least, did you try to draw?

Comment: I've attached the draw